# Onboarding List - Clicking a list to populate a new list for each individual?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list

New to SharePoint, I'm trying to make a new employee onboarding list to track new hire training. I wanted to see if it's possible to have it so that when the hypothetical new employee clicks on the list from the SharePoint page it will automatically populate their own individual list. Any advice or resources that I can use to do this? Thanks in advance :')